# PHP, reset txt - button

Tags: php, html

i wanna make a reset button for my analysis page. in this page, there are textfiles included. by clicking on the reset button, i want them to reset the assigned text file. for example:

```
<h4>Analysis</h4>
<h5>searchinputs</h5>
<input type="submit" value="empty" style="margin-top: 20px;"/>
</form>
<p>
<?php include("searchinputs.txt"); ?>
</p>
<h5>contact form</h5>
<input type="submit" value="empty" onclick="" style="margin-top: 20px;"/>
<p>
<?php include("contact.txt"); ?>
</p>
<h5>uploads</h5>
<input type="submit" value="empty" onclick="" style="margin-top: 20px;"/>
<p>
<?php include("../uploaded_data/info.txt"); ?>
</p>
```

I already tried this:

```
<form action="<?php $fp=fopen("searchinputs.txt", "w"); fclose($fp); ?>">
<input type="submit" value="empty" style="margin-top: 20px;"/>
</form>
<p>
<?php include("searchinputs.txt"); ?>
</p>
```

And this:

```
<form action="clear.php" method="post">
```

clear.php:

```
<?php
$fp=fopen("searchinputs.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

But both ways didn't work out. the txt file was emptied immediently after accessing the site.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve?
From what I understood you have a text file  that contains the values of the form.
When a user clears the from, you want to clear the text file as well?

Comment: the form is a search mask. the values, which are in the text file, has been grabbed out of the search mask. by clicking clear button 1, i only want to clear the text file 1, by clicking button 2, i want to reset the text file 2 and so on.

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP is performed on the server before the browser sees anything. The action contains PHP so that will execute on the server before the page is displayed, not after the action button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as clear.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action']=='empty'){
$fp=fopen("searchinputs.txt", "w");
fclose($fp);
}
```

This code as your form

```
<form action="clear.php" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="empty">
<input type="submit" value="empty" onclick="" />

</form>
```

And keep the searchinputs.txt file in the same directory.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: the script keeps deleting the content of the txt immediently after accessing the site :/

Comment: I think your script is calling the fopen() function when loading. Maybe you called another fopen() function in your script directly. The text file will never get empty itself without calling fopen() function.